# When to use {{""}} and just regular inline text in html?

Tags: html, angular

I'm working on an app and seeing some older code, and I noticed that there were double brackets {{}} with air-quotes inside containing the title instead of just placing a regular string inside.

Example: `<p> {{ "Title" }} </p>` instead of `<p> Title </p>`.

Is there a reason to do this? They both appear to do the same thing since double brackets just stringify any variable types placed in them. The app is an Angular app if that helps answer this question.

Comment: The two are equivalent.

Comment: Is one preferred over the other? Or is it pick and choose? Because I personally prefer the latter, it appears better in the IDE and helps me differentiate string-concatenated, coded variables from static, hardcoded innertext